# Can't generate dynamic UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm almost new in Swift programming. I'm using Swift 3 and the most recent version of Xcode, and I'm trying to do something that might be really easy for all of you, so here it goes:

I'm trying to populate a TableView dynamically with data retreived from a Firebase DB. To do so, I designed a Prototype cell, which contains a UIImageView, some of UILabels, and a Stepper. I think that Stepper and one of the UILabels doesn't need to be edited while generating. But I need to place a pic and edit 2 UILabels. Here's how I'm trying to do so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Set cell contents
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId)

    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(0) as! UIImageView
    var price:UILabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    var name:UILabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    let amount = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    name.text = productList[indexPath.row].name
    price.text = "" + (productList[indexPath.row].price?.description)! 
    let imageDict:NSDictionary = productList[indexPath.row].imageName!

    let image = downloadImageProductFromFirebase(append: imageDict["hash"] as! String)
    imageView.image = image


    return cell!
}
```

When I run the application, here's the error I found:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCellContentView' (0x10442bff8) to 'UIImageView' (0x10441c738).

But there's something good, I know that data are retreived properly from Firebase, cause it's printed over console before generating TableView cells.

Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: `let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(0) as! UIImageView` is finding the contentView of the cell because `0` is the default tag value for a view.  Use another tag value for your `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the content view of the tableview cell has the tag 0 already. you could give the image view another tag number or even better: create a custom subclass and connect @IBOutlets to the cell. This makes it type-safer and you even get autocomplete when accessing your views.

Comment: Superb! As vacawama, you solved it at first try! Now I got another problem (excuse me if I'm too annoying): Error moved to the firsr UILabel that I'm trying to modify: Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x109cb1778) to 'UILabel' (0x109cad268). Any additional help?

Comment: Don't use tags. Create a custom UITableViewCell subclass, assign it to your tableview and create a bunch of @IBOutlets and connect your labels to them. Then cast the cell in cellForRowAt to your custom cell class and access the views directly.

Comment: Okay! Seems easy to do! Any tutorial I can follow to do so? =) Really thank you , man!

Comment: raywenderlich tableview

Answer (score 1):

My friend create a `UITabelViewCell` subclass and connect the IBOutlets for your `UIImageView` and `UILabel` there and call them in the `cellForRowAt`. This is the right what to do it.

Here is how:

1. Create a UITableViewCell subclass
   Click on File---> New---> Cocoa Touch---> then choose subclass of `UITableViewCell` and write down the name of the class for example : `ProductsTableViewCell`
2. Click on your Dynamic cell prototype in your storyboard then click on the Identity inspector in the custom class change the class name to `ProductsTableViewCell`
3. Add your UIImageView and UILabels in the cell then create IBOutlets to them in the ProductsTableViewCell.swift file. The subclass we have created in step one.
4. Now in your `cellForRowAt` function call the IBOutlets of this prototype cell and change its contents.
   Example code:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId) as! ProductsTableViewCell

   cell.imageView.image = downloadImageProductFromFirebase(append: imageDict["hash"] as! String)
   cell.nameLabel.text = productList[indexPath.row].name
   cell.priceLabel.text = "" + (productList[indexPath.row].price?.description)!

   return cell
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot man! And thanks to your friend also! It really helped me!